# hoopla-api using ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, curl

I want to make use of the hoopla-api which from their website uses "CURL" and I need to make HTTP "POST, GET" using C#.

They mention that any Questions related to development posted on stackoverflow but I didn't see any post from anyone who asked a question. or perhaps it is just too easy for many people to get this up.

Here is their link https://developer.hoopla.net/docs/authentication

I am not sure how to properly implement this in C#:

Below is my sample GET method.

```
        string res;
        
        string client_id = "myclientid";
        string client_secret = "mysecret";
        string auth = client_id + ":" + client_secret;

        string ContentType = "application/json";

        string url = @"https://api.hoopla.net/users";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(client_id, client_secret);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + auth);
        request.ContentType = ContentType;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            res = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

and from their site they do have a python script that imports request module. but not sure if python has this module.

Here is their code :

```
        import requests

        client_id = 'your-generated-client-id'
        client_secret = 'your-generated-client-secret'
        host = 'https://api.hoopla.net'

        auth_params = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id':  client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret}
        r = requests.post( host+'/oauth2/token', params = auth_params )
        access_token = r.json()['access_token']

         request_headers = {
'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token,
'Accept':'application/vnd.hoopla.api-descriptor+json'
}

      r = requests.get( host+'/',headers = request_headers )
        }
```

Can anyone assist me in getting this in C#?

Comment: First of all its not a GET Call ..It's a POST..Read their  API guide carefully

Comment: hi @too_cool ; I have read the document and I am trying to get
the user as they indicated here

Examples




cURL 
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer a0b1c2' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.hoopla.user+json' 'https://api.hoopla.net/users/24a65e12-3cfc-42a3-a0f9-f0d2573e1a74'